# Can a foreigner with permanent residence status in Mexico fly within MX with only the permanent residency card, or is the passport also required

Tags: air-travel, passports, paperwork, mexico, residency

I am a US citizen who lives full time in Mexico with Permanent Resident status. If I fly, say from Mexico City to Oaxaca, can I do it with my residency card alone, or must I bring my US passport as well?

Answer (score 3):

Information on the Internet on this topic is inconsistent.

Our [previous advice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66313/what-documentation-does-a-mexican-citizen-need-to-fly-domestically-within-mexico) on a similar topic cites the [AICM website](https://www.aicm.com.mx/en/passengers/faqs) which says (in English) that

> Foreigners [require a] boarding pass and valid passport

The Mexican government [airport administration says](https://www.gob.mx/asa/acciones-y-programas/informacion-para-el-viajero) as well:

> Los pasajeros internacionales deberán portar siempre su pasaporte y visas correspondientes.
>
> [International passengers should always carry their passports and corresponding visas.]

However, the airline [Volaris says](https://cms.volaris.com/es/informacion-util/antes-de-tu-vuelo/documentos-y-requisitos-de-viaje/):

> **Extranjeros**: una identificación oficial vigente con fotografía original en físico (no fotocopias ni digital).
>
> - Pasaporte vigente
> - Residencia vigente
> - Alguna otra identificación oficial vigente
>
> [**Foreigners**: a valid official photo ID with in physical form (no photocopies nor digital copies).
>
> - Valid passport
> - Valid residence card
> - Some other valid official ID]

Aeromexico [provides a fairly length list of IDs they say are acceptable for domestic flights](https://aeromexico.com/es-mx/informacion-de-vuelos/documentos-para-viajar), and includes (among other options), curiously, an FM3 temporary residence card but not a permanent residence card.

So, my guess is, probably you'll be okay. But it is possible that some security guard adhering strictly to one of these lists would decide your residence card is not okay, and so you would be wise to bring your passport with you if it is at all an option.

[English translations of Spanish text above are my own and thus unofficial.]

Comment: "But it is possible that some security guard adhering strictly to one of these lists would decide your residence card is not okay" Unlikely.  Residents are not considered/treated as "foreigners" in Mexico (from an official/government statepoint).  You enter the country through the Mexican National lanes and only need to show Resident ID there, it's much the same elsewhere.  Where these sites refer to "foreigners" and/or "international visitors" it is not referring to legal residents of Mexico.

Comment: "International passengers" will likely refer to passengers flying to or from another country, like Mexicans flying to Italy, not Italians flying within Mexico.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, legal residents of Mexico can use their residency ID card (Permanente or Temporal) as identification for domestic flights within Mexico.

Comment: Midavalo, how do you know that? Only personal experience?

Comment: @Willeke I live in Mexico as a permanent resident.  Residents in Mexico are treated much the same way as locals when it comes to travel (and pretty much anything else official/government related). See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/117667/40422